# Inserting into a table with Psycopg2: Do Nothing on Conflict

Tags: python, psycopg2

Hello here is my current query:

```
        query = sql.SQL("insert into {schema}.{table} ({fields}) values ({placeholder}) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET {updates}").format(
        schema=sql.Identifier(self.schema),
        table=sql.Identifier(tbl_name),
        fields=sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(field_name) for field_name in column_names_lst),
        placeholder=sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() for field_value in column_data_lst),
        updates = ', '.join(f"{column_name} = '{column_value}'" for column_name, column_value
                               in tbl_data.items())
    )
```

It worked before adding the ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE part, and adding the updates parameter, but since then I required to make some columns into the primary key for some of the target tables.

I have something wrong with my syntax but can't seem to debug it, getting a TypeError:

```
Composed elements must be Composable, got...
```

Any insight would be helpful, this is a new library for me.

Comment: Is it possible you are updating one field in a multi-part primary key?  That's a "composed element".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updates` is just a composed string, it might be better to make use of `psycopg2.sql`:

```
schema = 'public'
tbl_name = 'testTable'
column_names_lst = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
column_data_lst = (1, 2, 3)
tbl_data = dict(zip(column_names_lst, column_data_lst))

query = sql.SQL(
    "insert into {schema}.{table} ({fields}) values ({placeholder}) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET {updates}"
).format(
    schema=sql.Identifier(schema),
    table=sql.Identifier(tbl_name),
    fields=sql.SQL(', ').join(
        sql.Identifier(field_name) for field_name in column_names_lst
    ),
    placeholder=sql.SQL(', ').join(
        sql.Placeholder() for field_value in column_data_lst
    ),
    updates=sql.SQL(', ').join(
        [
            sql.SQL("{}={}").format(sql.Identifier(k), sql.Placeholder())
            for k in column_names_lst
        ]
    )
)

print(query.as_string(cur))
# duplicate values in order to fill UPDATE values
allValues = column_data_lst + column_data_lst
print(cur.mogrify(query, allValues).decode('utf-8'))
```

Out:

```
insert into "public"."testTable" ("column_1", "column_2", "column_3") values (%s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET "column_1"=%s, "column_2"=%s, "column_3"=%s
insert into "public"."testTable" ("column_1", "column_2", "column_3") values (1, 2, 3) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET "column_1"=1, "column_2"=2, "column_3"=3
```