# Cant compose elements in python postgre sql statement

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to generate some sql for a python update script I want to make it so it reads in a json file and then extracts columns name

```
 def insert_payout(payout, items, node_name):#TODO add data source in pycharm

     vals = []
     nftDict = json.loads(nft)
     nftList = list(nftDict.keys())
     table = 'consortia.public.' + node_name
col_list = []

     for i in range(len(nftList)):
         col_list.append(str({nftList[i]}))
         vals.append(payout)

     base_sql = sql.SQL(
         '''INSERT INTO {} ({}) 
         VALUES ({})
         '''). \
         format(sql.Identifier(table),
                sql.SQL(", ").join(map(sql.Identifier, col_list)),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(col_list))
           )
     

      conn = None

      try:
          # read database configuration
         params = setparams()
         # connect to the PostgreSQL database
          conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
         # create a new cursor
          cur = conn.cursor()
         # execute the INSERT statement
         #cur.execute(base_sql, vals)
         # commit the changes to the database
         conn.commit()
         # close communication with the database
          cur.close()
      except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
         print(error)
     finally:
         if conn is not None:
             conn.close()


  if __name__ == '__main__':
          
         insert_payout(7.4, item_json, 'test_write_table')
```

Error is

```
 TypeError: Composed elements must be Composable, got 'N' instead
```

New Error is:

```
  "ItemUniqueName31": [
    "Item_ID_Number31",
    "<something31>",
    "BooleanActive"
],
"ItemUniqueName32": [
    "Item_ID_Number32",
    "<something32>",
    "BooleanActive"
]
 }


 dict is not a sequence
```

Newest error

```
 relation "consortia.public.test_write_table" does not exist
```

LINE 1: INSERT INTO "consortia.public.test_write_table" ("{'ItemUniqu...
^

And I am not adding the operator correctly I used this answer as a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73135956/when-create-table-psycopg2-errors-syntaxerror-syntax-error-at-end-of-input/73156525#73156525) once I get this working I am going to work in the vals

Comment: Have a look there, how to do it dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66499593/inserting-into-a-table-with-psycopg2-do-nothing-on-conflict/66505413#66505413

Comment: 1) This `for i in range(len(colList)): col_list.append({"col_name": colList[i]})` can be simplified to `for col in colList: col_list.append({"col_name": col})`. 2) In `for col in col_list:` the indentation is off, is that just a copy and paste error? 3) Add the complete error message to the question. 4)  Where is `nftList` coming from in `composed_list.append(sql.Composed(nftList[i]))`?

Comment: What is the structure for `payout`? I don't see `vals = {"val": payout}` working in `cur.execute(base_sql, vals)`. Basically  you  have made this more complicated then it needs to be. My answer that you linked to was for a complicated situation and does not apply to this case. Take a look at the `INSERT` examples here [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html), in particular under *class psycopg2.sql.Placeholder(name=None)* for a simpler solution.

Comment: Not working for two reasons 1) This "consortia.public.test_write_table" needs to be this "public"."test_write_table". Assuming `consortia` is database name there is no point in having it as there are no cross database references in Postgres.  To get proper identifier you need to do `sql.Identifier("public", "test_write_table")` 2) This `("{'ItemUniqu...` is going to fail as that is not a valid column name. Looks like you are not properly fetching the column names into `colList`.

Comment: You should start with a simple test case where you hard code the values and then step by step make it more dynamic. Sprinkle with `print()` to see what the values are actually being used for the identifiers and the data values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler solution:

Updated to deal with schema qualifying table name.

```
# Make table name a tuple for later unpacking in sql.Identifier to
# build schema qualified name.
table = ("public", "test_table")
colList = ['test', 'test2', 'test3']
base_sql = sql.SQL(
         '''INSERT INTO {} ({}) 
         VALUES ({})
         '''). \
         format(sql.Identifier(*table), # * unpack tuple to get schema qualification.
                sql.SQL(", ").join(map(sql.Identifier, colList)),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(colList))
                )

print(base_sql.as_string(con))                                                                                                                                        
INSERT INTO "public"."test_table" ("test", "test2", "test3") 
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
```

**UPDATE**

To illustrate what I mean by passing the values in correctly, as discussed in comments below:

```
\d test_table 
                  Table "public.test_table"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 test   | integer           |           |          | 
 test2  | character varying |           |          | 
 test3  | boolean           |           |          | 

vals = [1, 'dog', False]

cur.execute(base_sql, vals)    

con.commit()

select * from test_table ;
 test | test2 | test3 
------+-------+-------
    1 | dog   | f
```

Comment: Dude youre seriously the best, I updated it correctly I think but I am having a minor error with what looks to be where the sql generator is loading the json values to build the statement. Can you have a look?

Comment: As I said in my comment above; 'What is the structure for payout? I don't see vals = {"val": payout} working in cur.execute(base_sql, vals).'. The values you pass in have to match the parameters `VALUES (%s, %s, %s)`, so either a list or tuple of values.

Comment: That would make sense I updated the error its showing parts of the JSON object I am passing it

Comment: I guess I am not seeing where its putting the json in and not the extracted list

Comment: The error `dict is not a sequence` is telling you what `vals = {"val": payout}` is showing you. `cur.execute(base_sql, vals)` is resolving to `cur.execute(base_sql,  {"val": payout})` and that does not map to `VALUES (%s, %s, %s ...)`. To get it to map `vals` needs to be a `list` or `tuple` of values that will each match up with the `%s` parameters in `VALUES()`.

Comment: See UPDATE for example of what I am talking about.

Comment: I am updating now I am not sure why but now I am getting an error on the table